# Terraform doesn't like my variables that contain lists of strings in my NACL block, can't figure out why

Tags: terraform

I wanted to make a rule that used a range of cidr blocks to cut down on the number of rules. I can't seem to get terraform to accept the variables or data output as strings

code:

```
data "aws_ip_ranges" "az_s3" {
  regions = ["region-1"]
  services = ["s3"]
}

variable "wan_range" {
  description = "WAN cidr ranges"
  type        = list(string)
  default     = ["10.0.0.0/8", "172.16.0.0/16", "192.168.0.0/24"]
  
}

resource "aws_network_acl" "NACL_1" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.sec_vpc.id
  subnet_ids = [aws_subnet.private_subnet.id]
  count = length(var.sd_wan_range)
  egress = [
 {
      protocol   = "tcp"
      rule_no    = 100
      action     = "allow"
      cidr_block = data.aws_ip_ranges.az_s3.cidr_blocks
      from_port  = 80
      to_port    = 80
      icmp_code  = 0
      icmp_type  = 0
      ipv6_cidr_block = null
    },
   {
      protocol   = "tcp"
      rule_no    = 200
      action     = "allow"
      cidr_block = var.wan_range[count.index]
      from_port  = 32768
      to_port    = 65535
      icmp_code  = 0
      icmp_type  = 0
      ipv6_cidr_block = null
    }
  ]
```

Here is the error from plan:

```
├────────────────
│     │ count.index is 0
│     │ data.aws_ip_ranges.az_s3.cidr_blocks is list of string with 6 elements
│     │ var.wan_range is list of string with 3 elements
│ 
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "egress": element 2: attribute "cidr_block": string required.
```

Comment: What is the value of `sd_wan_range`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to index on `data.aws_ip_ranges.az_s3.cidr_blocks` as well. The `cidr_blocks` attribute is a list.

e.g.

```
cidr_block = data.aws_ip_ranges.az_s3.cidr_blocks[count.index]
```